# Twitter API character encoding issue in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

I'm trying to integrate Twitter API V1.1 with a PHP website. On Twitter my tweet appears as:

> *SWLaw : Farm & Country is out! http://paper.li/SWLAWCOUK/1346753760 … ▸ Top stories today via @CountrySportsSW @jonesFW @NFUBFGmag*

However, on my site the tweet appears as:

> *RT @SWLawCountry: SWLaw : Farm & Country is out! http://t.co/AU7WCxUxf5â–¸ Top stories today
>   vi@CountrySportsSWS@jonesFWF@NFUBFGmagag*

Note the additional characters and special characters.

This seems to be a character encoding issue because the Twitter API (I believe) returns JSON encoded as UTF-8 whereas my web page is encoded as iso-8859-1. I've attempted to fix the issue using PHP's iconv function as follows:

```
$new_text = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $new_text);
```

This produces the following output:

> *RT @SWLawCountry: SWLaw : Farm & Country is out! http://t.co/AU7WCxUxf5 Top stories today
>   vi@CountrySportsSWS@jonesFWF@NFUBFGmagag*

Note that although the special characters have been removed, the additional characters remain and there are missing spaces between some words.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do would be to use UTF-8 for your site. This is pretty much the de-facto standard on the web these days and can encode virtually any and all characters in use on computers to date.

If it's difficult for you to switch over, you can represent characters that are not encodable in ISO-8859 by encoding them as HTML entities instead:

```
echo htmlentities($new_text, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

This should preserve all characters, even in an ISO-8859 context.